# Moving point along the vector

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, 3d, floating-point

I'm making a video game in which a ball is moving towards a player.  So, I have a point $P$ describing the point where the player is, and a point $B$ describing where the ball is.  I know that we can represent the direction from $B$ to $A$ as a vector.

I want to move the ball a small amount towards the player, along the direction of this vector.  Is there a simple way to determine the new coordinates of the ball?

Comment: Where exactly are you running into problems?  There's many ways to do this, but it depends on how computationally efficient you want the solution...

Comment: I just want to move the collision point small distance in the direction of the player. Is there a way I can move the point along the vector?

Comment: I've made substantial edits to this question, in hopes of triggering a reopoen vote.  Because the question is 4 years old and my answer was accepted, I believe it is ok to take some liberty in interpreting the original post for clarity's sake.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let's say you have a vector $\vec P = [P_1, P_2, P_3]$ that represents the point's location in space.  Another vector, $\vec B = [B_1, B_2, B_3]$ represents the ball's (or bullet's or whatever) position in space.

The vector $\vec {BP}$ between the two is:
$$\vec{BP} = \vec P - \vec B = [P_1 - B_1, P_2- B_2, P_3-B_3]$$

So, if you want the ball to move *all* the way to the player, you would say:
$$\vec B_{new} = \vec B + \vec{BP}$$

Or, if you want the ball to move only $1/100$th of the way to the player, you would say:
$$\vec B_{new} = \vec B + \frac{1}{100}\vec{BP}$$

In general, to move some small $\epsilon$ to the player:
$$\vec B_{new} = \vec B + \epsilon\vec{BP}$$

Comment: Thanks! so if you want to move the point just have add it to vector. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I'd find a linear function that connects a player with a ball:

$$
f(x) = ax + b
\\
\iff
\\
a = \frac{P_y-B_y}{P_x-B_x}
\\
b = P_y - a \cdot P_x
$$

To get new coordinates of the ball, we calculate normal vector length:

$$
\vert\vert v \vert\vert = \sqrt{1+a^2}
$$

and use it to get x-translation - for every $n$ pixels run along our line:

$$
\vec{x} = \frac{n}{\vert\vert v \vert\vert}
$$

For example, if ball has passed 10 pixels along our line:

$$
\vec{x} = \frac{10}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}
$$

Finally, new coordinates of the ball are as follows:

$$
x' = x + \vec{x}
\\
y' = f(x')
$$

where $x$ is current x-position of the ball.